# Comparing HashMap in JUnitTesting

Tags: java, unit-testing, hashmap, junit5

I Have To:

1. Write a function that accepts an array/list of strings, counts the occurrence of each string, and then returns a data structure with each unique string and the number of times it occurred. For example, given an input that contains:

[“apple”, “bat”, “apple”, “car”]

the function should return a data structure that has a count of 2 for “apple”, 1 for “bat” and 1 for “car”.

2. Write the unit test coverage for my solution. Cover the permutations that ensure positive/negative functionality is correct. As well, cover meaningful edge cases to ensure both correct functionality and to ensure no errors with code execution.

Now, i have done the task one, here is the code:

```
package Testing;
import java.util.*;
class CountString{
public static void main(String []args){
    List strings = Arrays.asList("appLe","b at","APPle","car!");
    Map<String,Integer> datastructure = countStrings(strings);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : datastructure.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
    }
}

public static Map<String,Integer>countStrings(List<String> words){
    Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    List<String>newList = new ArrayList<>();
    String regex = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    regex+=regex.toUpperCase();
    String w;
    for(String s:words){
        w="";
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
            if(regex.contains(s.charAt(i)+"")){
                w+=s.charAt(i)+"";
            }
        }
        newList.add(w.toLowerCase());
    }
    String countedWords = "";
    int count;
    for(int i=0;i<newList.size();i++){
        count=1;
        if(!countedWords.contains(newList.get(i))){
            for(int j=i+1;j<newList.size();j++){
                if(newList.get(i).equals(newList.get(j))){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            countedWords+=newList.get(i)+"";
            map.put(newList.get(i),count);
        }

    }
    return map;
    }
}
```

Now i have to design the unit testing of this but i am little confuse in comparing hashmap, kindly help me in that,

Here is a little try which i have done:

```
package Testing;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class JUnitTest {

@Test
void test() {
    CountString test = new CountString();
    List strings = Arrays.asList("appLe","b at","APPle","car!");
    Map<String,Integer> output = test.countStrings(strings);

    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : output.entrySet()) {
        assertEquals(expecteds, output);


        }
    }
}
```

I cannot find out how assertEqual function works in Map.

Comment: That count method seems overly complicated. Since you're already getting a list of strings why don't you just check the map for those? Would `"b at"` really have to be mapped to `"bat"`? Would the case be relevant? If not would it be ok to convert everything to lower/upper case?

Comment: As for the test: `HashMap#equals()` returns true if the other map contains the exact same key-value pairs (as defined by the key and value `equals()` implementations which for `String` and `Integer` are as expected) and thus you only need to manually build a map that would look like the one you expect to get - then just compare the two. Alternatively compare the maps as follows: 1) Are the sizes equal? If not there's a difference. 2) Loop over the entries of one map, get the corresponding entry of the second map and compare.

Comment: @Thomas Yes Sir! · my solution should ignore differences in upper/lowercase: “Apple” should be treated as “apple”

· my solution should trim/strip/remove all leading/trailing/inner whitespace: “ app le ” should be treated as “apple”

· my solution should trim/strip/remove any non-alphanumeric characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9): “apple!” should be treated as “apple”

Comment: I see. Note that `String regex = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` is misleading: you're not actually using a regex here - that's more like an "alphabet". If you actually want to use a regex could do something like this: `word.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]+","")` - this would replace all sequences of unwanted charaters with an empty string, i.e. it would remove them. Thus `"tr UcK2!".toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]+","")` would result in `"truck"`. Here you'd _really_ use a regex: `[^a-z]+` which means any sequence of characters that's not one of "a to z".

Answer (score 0):

I Have tried my self, and this solution has worked for me!

```
package Testing;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class JUnitTest {

@Test
void test() {
    CountString test = new CountString();
    List strings = Arrays.asList("appLe","b at","APPle","car!","truck!","tr UcK2");
    Map<String,Integer> output = test.countStrings(strings);
    Map<String,Integer> expecteds = new HashMap<>();
    expecteds.put("apple", 2);
    expecteds.put("bat", 1);
    expecteds.put("car", 1);
    expecteds.put("truck", 2);
    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : output.entrySet()) {
        assertEquals(expecteds.get(entry.getKey()), output.get(entry.getKey()));


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats a good start, I'd just add the size check as well. Imagine you'd add `expecteds.put("banana", 1);` - your test would still pass because all the output is contained in `expecteds` but not all expected entries are in the output. Just changing it the other way round might not be sufficient as well because the output might contain entries that are not expected. However, if you check that the sizes are equal then if all entries of one map are contained in the other you automatically know that none of the maps contains additional entries.